# What is the current encryption method used on GSM currently?

Tags: reference-request, transport-security

I am currently doing a mini project which sniffs GSM packets using gr-gsm and wireshark.

I was wondering if anyone knows what is the name of the current encryption algorithm method used on GSM?

Comment: Did you try to find that on Google?

Comment: Google just talks about history unfortunately.

Comment: A5/1, /2, /3 for voice, GEA/0 - /4 for data (GPRS). [See Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM#GSM_Security)